# Odoo Qweb Report Manufacturing Order - commitment date and Url

Tags: date, url, field, qweb

I would modify existing report_mrporder by adding a field.

1. Manufacturing order report of a product has a field sale_order_id but I am not able to have a field contained in sale_order_line of product.
   In this case I need to have a commitment date of a product (contained in sale_order_line).
2. I have installed this module https://github.com/OCA/knowledge/tree/12.0/document_url.
   I use this module to attach a drawing to my products and I would attach to mrp_order_report a second page that contains this drawing (PDF)

Thank to all

Comment: what exactly the issue you have?